# What are possible reasons for a RenderBox not meeting its constraints?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

My `RenderBox` throws the following assertion:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderBox does not meet its constraints.
Constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=411.4)
Size: Size(411.4, 411.4)
```

Looking at the implementation of the failing assertion, I found out that [`isSatisfiedBy`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/BoxConstraints/isSatisfiedBy.html) should actually not fail as the size is equal to the constraints.
Hence, I am wondering what causes this.

Through debugging I actually figured out that `size.height` is about `411.42857` while `constraints.maxHeight` is about `411.42855`. Thus I tried flooring the size, but oddly it does not help.

Comment: Wouldn't flooring the size make it 411, which still doesn't equal 411.4...?

Comment: @spkersten Well, the operator is `<=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the size was fixed, I solved it by applying what is [described here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderBox-class.html#layout):

```
SizedBoxed(width: 411.2, height: 411.2, child: MyRenderObjectWidget())
```

For this to work, I removed the override of `performLayout` and added the following to my `RenderObject`:

```
@override
get sizedByParent => true;

@override
performResize() => size = constraints.smallest;
```